# How to create multiple validation methods for one endpoint?

Tags: json, go, endpoint

I want to make a validation api in order to validate a set of json requests regarding specific set of rules. To do that I want to use just one endpoint and call functions that correspond to the specific json struct. I know that there is no method overloading in go so I am kind of stumped.

```
...

type requestBodyA struct {
    SomeField   string `json:"someField"`
    SomeOtherField  string `json:"someOtherField"`
}

type requestBodyB struct {
    SomeDifferentField   string `json:"someDifferentField"`
    SomeOtherDifferentField  string `json:"someOtherDifferentField"`
}



type ValidationService interface {
    ValidateRequest(ctx context.Context, s string) (err error)
}

type basicValidationService struct{}

...
```

So in order to validate lots of different json requests, is it better to create structs for each and every json request? Or should I create these dynamically? How can I know what kind of request is sent if I only have one endpoint?

Comment: "How can I know what kind of request is sent if I only have one endpoint" unless you design a way into the API, you can't, regardless of what language you're using. That's just an impossible API design. There has to be some way to detect what the client is trying to do.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single endpoint/rpc that has to accept different JSON types, you'll need to tell it how to distinguish between them, somehow. One option is to have something like:

```
type request struct {
  bodyA *requestBodyA
  bodyB *requestBodyB
}
```

Then, populate these fields in a container JSON object appropriately. The `json` module will only populate `bodyA` if a `bodyA` key is present, otherwise leaving it a `nil`, and so on.

Here's a more complete example:

```
type RequestBodyFoo struct {
    Name    string
    Balance float64
}

type RequestBodyBar struct {
    Id  int
    Ref int
}

type Request struct {
    Foo *RequestBodyFoo
    Bar *RequestBodyBar
}

func (r *Request) Show() {
    if r.Foo != nil {
        fmt.Println("Request has Foo:", *r.Foo)
    }
    if r.Bar != nil {
        fmt.Println("Request has Bar:", *r.Bar)
    }
}

func main() {
    bb := []byte(`
    {
        "Foo": {"Name": "joe", "balance": 4591.25}
    }
    `)

    var req Request
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bb, &req); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.Show()

    var req2 Request
    bb = []byte(`
    {
        "Bar": {"Id": 128992, "Ref": 801472}
    }
    `)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bb, &req2); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req2.Show()
}
```

Another option is to do it more dynamically with maps, but it's likely that the method above will be sufficient.

Comment: That makes total sense. Thank you for your input! I created a solution based on this approach.